# How to insert a new object OOP Matlab?

Tags: matlab, class, oop, object

I need to insert an object/class in a simulator based OOP-matlab (LTE VIENNA SIM) so I wonder how I could discover the architecture of this software or how to insert my object.
How is every file mapped to others?
Thank you.

Comment: To discover the architecture of the simulator you'll have to take a look at its documentation or directly at the code. It's a very good simulator, but it has a somewhat intricate structure

Comment: thank you for your quick answer
I have read the documentation and i have tried to create new scheduler but i did not succeed,

Comment: Generally, I need to know how to insert/add a class, or whatever I want to , into a simulator that I didn’t developed 
What I have to do for this purpose, how to discover the path to follow , the variables, the arborescence…. steps or advises ((I’m not a developer I need this for study purposes)